# Silverlight ListBoxItem DataTemplate Button problems!?

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, sketchflow

I am trying to build a ListBox with items that have edit states. I created a separate DataTemplate for the Normal and Edit modes, But once i change the ContentTemplate on the ContentPresenter I am loosing the event bubbleup from the button's withing the DataTempaltes (meaning that the button clicks have no action anymore).

Here is the code:

```
<UserControl.Resources>

    <DataTemplate x:Key="NormalDT">
        <StackPanel>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Property1}"/>
            <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Property2, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
            <Button Content="Test" Click="Button_Click" />
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="EditDT">
        <StackPanel>
            <TextBox Text="{Binding Property1}"/>
            <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Property2, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
            <Button Content="Test" Click="Button_Click" />
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
    <Style x:Key="ListBoxItemStyle1" TargetType="ListBoxItem">
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="3"/>
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Left"/>
        <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Top"/>
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
        <Setter Property="TabNavigation" Value="Local"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                    <Grid Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To=".35" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="fillColor"/>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To=".55" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="contentPresenter"/>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="SelectionStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Unselected"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Selected">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To=".75" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="fillColor2"/>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="FocusStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Focused">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility" Storyboard.TargetName="FocusVisualElement">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                    <Visibility>Visible</Visibility>
                                                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Visibility)" Storyboard.TargetName="contentPresenterEdit">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                    <Visibility>Visible</Visibility>
                                                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Visibility)" Storyboard.TargetName="contentPresenter">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                    <Visibility>Collapsed</Visibility>
                                                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Unfocused"/>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <Rectangle x:Name="fillColor" Fill="#FFBADDE9" IsHitTestVisible="False" Opacity="0" RadiusY="1" RadiusX="1"/>
                        <Rectangle x:Name="fillColor2" Fill="#FFBADDE9" IsHitTestVisible="False" Opacity="0" RadiusY="1" RadiusX="1"/>
                        <ContentPresenter x:Name="contentPresenter" 
                                          ContentTemplate="{StaticResource NormalDT}" 
                                          Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" 
                                          HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" 
                                          Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"/>

                        <ContentPresenter x:Name="contentPresenterEdit" 
                                          ContentTemplate="{StaticResource EditDT}" 
                                          Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" 
                                          HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" 
                                          Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
                        <Rectangle x:Name="FocusVisualElement" RadiusY="1" RadiusX="1" Stroke="#FF6DBDD1" StrokeThickness="1" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</UserControl.Resources>

<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White" DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource SampleDataSource}}">
    <ListBox Height="263" Margin="33,54,366,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource NormalDT}" ItemsSource="{Binding Collection}" ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource ListBoxItemStyle1}"/>

</Grid>
```

Any idea on how I can get the button_click event working in my situation?

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some reason that I don't know, the `Visibility` animation defined in your focus visual state is causing this issue.

Try animating `Opacity` instead and it should work.

**UPDATE**

Actually, your code does work in WPF. I think it is a bug in Silverlight. If you attach a `MouseLeftButtonDown` event to a `TextBlock` it actually will fire, however it's not the same case for `Buttons` and `CheckBoxes`.

Then I suspect it could be this but I am not 100% sure...

> Prior to Silverlight 5, ButtonBase does not change the visual state
>   when Visibility is set to Collapsed, so when the control is visible
>   again, it stays in the visual state before it is made invisible.

Comment: YOU ARE GOLDEN Xin!!! :D 

I swapped the visibility manipulation with the opacity and now the button click bubbles up. SWEEEET! 

Thank you soooooo much!